# encrypting database password so that in logs it should not be there

Tags: hibernate, logging, log4j

I have developed a hibernate application of one to one relationship through join concept below but the one thing that I have discovered that in the database configuration file that cfg.xml file we provide the database password and also in the logs that I was checking that database password was being there , please advise how that database password can be set in encrypted in logs at least , using log4j

Answer (score 0):

If this is a production system, it is strongly advised to not store database passwords in configuration files and be obtained from a key store. In our company, we use a centralized key store and overridden the Driver interface that gets the credentials from the Key store at run time using the passphrase corresponding to the [User, Password] and initializes the data source. This would make the Hibernate infrastructure to see the passphrase and not the user/password. HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot any example or url please share so that I can grasp more